# Does voting to close a bountied question consume your close vote?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19331/what-are-some-good-game-programming-short-courses) is, in my opinion, overly subjective, discussion-oriented, and potentially time-sensitive -- in short, a bad question for this site. I tried to vote to close it a while ago, but I was told that I couldn't do that because it had an open bounty.

Now that the bounty has been awarded, I went back and tried to vote it for closure again, but I'm now told that I already voted *even though I don't see my vote in the close tally* (as I write this, the close link says "close," indicating nobody voted to close it yet, instead of "close (n)" as I would expect if there were any votes recorded for it).

Note that at some point after I was told I can't vote to close questions with bounties, I also flagged the question, which may have something to do with the behavior I'm seeing.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be forgetting something; you actually *did* successfully vote to close this question; precisely on November 10 at 16:17 UTC, about three hours after the bounty was awarded.

Yours was however the only close vote, and hence it was [automatically expired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581) yesterday.

Comment: Oh. Oops. I feel silly now. Thanks for the information!